# Upload and use custom JavaScript file in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

My project has a crossword. The client would like to upload JavaScript files and change the pattern.

How do I make the upload file and include the JavaScript in the front end of the website? The file is getting uploaded but it is not showing up in source code.

Comment: you need to provide some of your code: how do you handle the upload? where is the js file embedded afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is for SilverStripe 3.1.

This example adds a JavaScript file upload to each page. In the Controller's `init()` function if a file has been uploaded we load it into the page:

**Page.php**

```php
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'CustomJavascriptFile' => 'File'
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $customJavascriptFile = UploadField::create('CustomJavascriptFile', 'Custom Javascript File');

        $customJavascriptFile->setFolderName('javascript');
        $customJavascriptFile->setAllowedExtensions(array('js'));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Javascript', $customJavascriptFile); 

        return $fields;
    }

}
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        if ($this->CustomJavascriptFileID) {
            Requirements::javascript($this->CustomJavascriptFile()->RelativeLink());
        }
    }
}
```

This method gives us a custom JavaScript file per page. We could alternatively have the file uploaded to the Config Settings instead so we can upload one file that is then loaded for the whole site.

First we need to extend SiteConfig. We need to declare the extension in our config.yml:

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
---
Name: site
After: 'framework/*','cms/*'
---
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
     - CustomSiteConfig
```

**CustomSiteConfig.php**

```php
class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'CustomJavascriptFile' => 'File'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {

        $customJavascriptFile = UploadField::create('CustomJavascriptFile', 'Custom Javascript File');

        $customJavascriptFile->setFolderName('javascript');
        $customJavascriptFile->setAllowedExtensions(array('js'));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Javascript', $customJavascriptFile); 
    }
}
```

**Page.php**

```php
class Page extends SiteTree {

}
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        $siteConfig = SiteConfig::current_site_config();

        if ($siteConfig->CustomJavascriptFileID) {
            Requirements::javascript($siteConfig->CustomJavascriptFile()->RelativeLink());
        }
    }
}
```